# Which color is colorAccent in Android Studio colors.xml?

Tags: android, kotlin, colors

Here's my colors.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

I think this was one of the new features in the new Android Studio Version (because I updated Android Studio recently).

Can someone please tell me where `colorAccent` went?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `colorPrimary`, `colorSecondary`, `colorAccent`... are **attributes** defined in the App Theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

They have **a reference** to a color resources defined in `colors.xml` (like `@color/purple_200`).

Using a `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` your `Button` is tinted by default by the  `colorPrimary` defined in your theme.

You can override it using something like:

```
    <Button
       app:background="?attr/colorSecondary"
```

or

```
    <Button
       app:background="@color/...."
```

If you are using an `AppCompat` theme the button is tinted by default by the  `colorAccent` defined in your theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Also in this case you can override it:

```
    <Button
       app:background="@color/...."
```

Comment: Oh ok I think that's the only answer.
Why did I not think of it before? 